# How to fit a Rectangle inside a Circle?

Tags: libgdx, geometry

So far I've tried creating another `Rectangle` to calculate the radius of an inner `Circle` with it's center and a point to the left side:

```java
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
Vector2 center = new Vector2();
otherRectangle.getCenter(center);
Vector2 side = new Vector2(otherRectangle.x, otherRectangle.y + otherRectangle.height / 2f);
float size = center.dst(side);
rectangle.setSize(size);
rectangle.setCenter(center);
```

But this makes the `rectangle` be too small and I'd like the corners of the square to be touching the circle border:

[image]

Comment: You need the diagonal of the square to be equal to the diameter of the circle. Sounds like a job for the Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: The square size should be `Math.sqrt(2) * radius`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5288316/nicolas) commented, the answer so the corners of the square touch the circle is to set its size to `Math.sqrt(2) * radius`